# Php mongo finding matching documents given an array

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query

I'd like to find documents from a collection that has for example a category 'cat'

i.e.

```
[{id: 0, name: 'cheetah', category: ['cat', 'has_claws']},
 {id: 1, name: 'lion', category: ['cat', 'has_claws', 'alpha']},
 {id: 2, name: 'fox', category: ['dog']},
 {id: 3, name: 'eagle' category: ['bird', 'has_claws']}
]
```

What does the query should look like? For example, I wanted to query allo animals that is in the category `has_claws`, I also wanted to make sure, there wouldn't be any duplicates, when I query using an array instead..

I.e. I want to query animals that is in `cats` and in `has_claws`

I thought using `$in` will suffice

```
$query   = array('category' => array('$in' => array('cat', 'has_claws')));
$animals = $animalModel->find($query);
```

is there a native function to do this,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want [`$all`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/all/)

```
$query   = array('category' => array('$all' => array('cat', 'has_claws')));
$animals = $animalModel->find($query);
```

Which means the field must have "both" values to be a match. The [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) operator instead means "either" of the values can match, so "three" of your documents as opposed to "two" that [`$all`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/all/) would match.

Also you named the field incorrectly in your question. Corrected to `"category"` here.

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be:-

```
db.collection.find( { category: { $in: [ 'cat', 'has_claws' ] } } )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to query for all the animals having category cat and has_claws with no duplicate you can use distinct function.

$query=array('name',array('category' => array('$in' => array('cats', 'has_claws'));
$result = $collection->distinct($query);